# SQL hackerrank weird output

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a problem with making multiple queries on hackerrank using mysql as when i provide it with the following queries:

```
SELECT CONCAT(Name,'(',LEFT(OCCUPATION,1),')')
FROM OCCUPATIONS
ORDER BY Name;
SELECT CONCAT('There are a total of ',COUNT(Occupation),' ',LOWER(Occupation),'s.')
FROM OCCUPATIONS
GROUP BY Occupation
ORDER BY COUNT(Occupation), Occupation;
```

this is the output:

```
    Aamina(D)
    Ashley(P)
    Belvet(P)
    Britney(P)
    Christeen(S)
    Eve(A)
    Jane(S)
    Jennifer(A)
    Jenny(S)
    Julia(D)
    Ketty(A)
    Kristeen(S)
    Maria(P)
    Meera(P)
    Naomi(P)
    Priya(D)
    Priyanka(P)
    Samantha(A)
    CONCAT('There are a total of ',COUNT(Occupation),' ',LOWER(Occupation),'s.')
    There are a total of 3 doctors.
    There are a total of 4 actors.
    There are a total of 4 singers.
    There are a total of 7 professors.
```

and i dont know why this line appears:

```
CONCAT('There are a total of ',COUNT(Occupation),' ',LOWER(Occupation),'s.')
```

in the output, this happens no matter how simple the query is;

I tried doing just

```
SELECT Name from OCCUPATIONS;
```

and still in the output i have whats between select and occupations so in this case Name, the same happen if i include more queries.

Comment: You haven't provided a column alias so by default the column expression is used.

Comment: Shouldn't `CONCAT(Name,'(',LEFT(OCCUPATION,1),')')` also be in the output then?

Comment: @Stu You are right in saying that without the alias the column expression is used but now how do i make it so that nothing appears and that there is no line break in the output as the task requires.